Does Israel have an AI system called 'Where's Daddy?' that preferentially targets Hamas in their homes, together with their families?
972 Mag:

Additional automated systems, including one called “Where’s Daddy?” also revealed here for the first time, were used specifically to track the targeted individuals and carry out bombings when they had entered their family’s residences.
The result, as the sources testified, is that thousands of Palestinians — most of them women and children or people who were not involved in the fighting — were wiped out by Israeli airstrikes, especially during the first weeks of the war, because of the AI program’s decisions.
“We were not interested in killing [Hamas] operatives only when they were in a military building or engaged in a military activity,” A., an intelligence officer, told +972 and Local Call. “On the contrary, the IDF bombed them in homes without hesitation, as a first option. It’s much easier to bomb a family’s home. The system is built to look for them in these situations.”

Is the existence of such a system (that tracks Hamas to their homes and then preferentially targets them there) corroborated by any other sources?

I've read the same in a German language newspaper (without labelling the system as "where's daddy"), but I don't have a link right now.  I think IDF describes this as "using civilians as human shields", and as far as I know, this claim is uncontroversial.

In case someone wonders how that location tracking is even possible: apparently the main method was [geo]locating their phone(s), based on the rest of the piece.

Might be hard to find another source, considering this is the result of investigative journalism and states that it is unveiled for the first time.  Looks like a very in-depth and well-researched article from a serious source.  If finding other sources now, those probably refer back to the +972 magazine article.

Part of the nature of journalism is often that sources must be kept anonymous for their own protection, and that such sources typically only speak to one outlet. So you're basically going to have to trust +972 that they're telling the truth when they say they spoke to six Israeli intelligence officers. "Is +972 generally trustworthy as a journalism outlet?" is a different question.

@user253751 Skeptics.se is the more pro-zionist site of StackExchange, I think even more than Judaism.se. Look at this answer from 2012 asking if Israelis can kill Palestinians with impunity, which has a very upvoted and accepted answer proving that the 100$ fines, wrist-slaps and other minor sentences of the 1% of the cases the IDF is obligated to prosecute (because there is video evidence) and which doesn't end in acquital (a no-suspectful-at-all 99.7% ratio) offer a clear case.

@user253751 I'd counter Rekesoft's argument by stating that Skeptics is the most pro-fact site, whereas politics.se, from what I've observed isn't. See this post.

Maybe
Here's the IDF official response to the article, the relevant part roughly translated to

The article "is riddled with inaccuracies and unfounded claims regarding the intelligence and operational processes concerning the attack on targets in the Gaza Strip, including the manner of operation of the Beshura system."
In general, the article presents things in a trending and misleading way. It can be assumed that the article is based on briefings and unauthorized sources, who were clearly not involved in the operational processes described in the article in recent months.

The "Beshura" (or "Besora") system is described as

Such a system is among the 'Beshura', which is used in war. This is a system that allows the use of automatic tools to produce targets at a fast pace, and works by improving accurate and high-quality intelligence material according to the requirement. With the help of artificial intelligence, and through the rapid and automatic extraction of updated intelligence - it produces a recommendation for the researcher, with the goal being that there will be a complete match between the machine's recommendation and the identification performed by a person.

This doesn't necessarily confirms or denies that

thousands of Palestinians — most of them women and children or people who were not involved in the fighting — were wiped out by Israeli airstrikes, especially during the first weeks of the war, because of the AI program’s decisions.

only that an AI system exists to help and acquire targets, and that a human (is supposed to be) involved in making the last decision.

I don't think a response from only IDF sources constitutes an answer.

@thosphor that's why it's a "Maybe", it is usually impossible to have a reliable third party verification of claims on confidential military equipment and methods. If you read the response (it's in Hebrew, as a non copyable image in a PDF) then the IDF source doesn't deny the claims, only says that there is a process and a human being involved, which to me adds credibility.

It would be helpful to highlight if the IDF response actually denies any specific claim made by the article - right now it reads like they're just rephrasing the claim without actually making any denials

@CJR, because the claim is not controversial. Families of high ranking Hamas activists were killed when their family member was targeted in his home. There is no argument about that. And many people see those death as acceptable. So does it matter if the targeting was made by AI or by a Human? Even if they were made by AI, a human would make the same decision. If you want to show a problem with AI targeting, you should show a case where a decision was made that a human would not approve. If we look at another use case of AI that is like criticizing AI for successfully parking a car.

@SIMEL I don't agree that AI deciding to kill thousands of civilians is like AI parking a car.  The claim is (among other things), that with the help of AI, Israel generates far more targets that they could do without, and therefore have been able to kill not only the families of high-ranking Hamas people, but also low-ranking ones, which they otherwise would leave out for practical purposes. Maybe some people think it's OK to murder the family of an important Hamas member but not of an unimportant one?

@gerrit, but the IDF sees it as an acceptable and preferable outcome. The claim would be bad if it would claim that AI caused for attacks to be approved that otherwise wouldn't be approved, Not that AI gave more attacks that were approved by a human, or that would be approved even if sourced by a Human. Hamas activists, low ranking or high ranking are in danger of being bombed, and if they do to their home, they knowingly bring that danger to their families, who also know the role and danger their father is in. Creating more targets is the role of AI.

@SIMEL I'm not sure what your point is.  The claim is that Israel has a system that targets Hamas members in their homes.  This answer points out that the IDF has not denied that such a system exists.  Whether it's okay to murder thousands of civilians is not relevant to the question.

I'm not sure that "the IDF was going to kill all those women and children anyway because that's what the IDF does" is really relevant to the claim. Nobody who asks about chatGPTs capabilities cares if a human could have given you the same output.

@CJR, The article tries to imply that AI made those decisions, and that a human would not have made them. You wanted the IDF to deny the allegations, but they wouldn't do it. But the targets are legitimate targets in the eyes of the IDF, AI merely helped the IDF to reach the result they wanted faster or better. Javelin missiles, HIMARS and JDAMS in Ukraine are also using AI to hit Russian targets, where is the article about "Ukraine is using AI to kill thousands of Russians"?

@CJR, a claim with merit would be to take an attack that a human wouldn't or shouldn't have authorized and to show that because of the involvement of AI, the attack still executed. For example if they would claim that the WKC convoy was attacked because of AI. But in that case it was actually human error that led to a tragic result.

I don't know why you think "an AI system is directing military strikes against civilian targets" is not a notable claim because the IDF would also choose to hit civilian targets without an AI system. It's notable no matter what the IDF's human-directed targeting does. I do not appreciate the whataboutism or the motte-and-bailey arguments, they're off-topic.

@CJR, because the answer to the question do militaries use AI in their targeting acquisition processes is yes to all armed groups. Even Isis and Al Qaida used Google Maps when planning their attacks. Putting the targets in an excel spread sheet and sorting them by priority is using AI to select targets. That's why you will not get a denial of "Does the IDF use AI in its target acquisition", this is the same as asking does the IDF use computers for its target acquisitions. Everyone uses AI, the only difference that supposedly the tool they use now is (supposedly) better than the previous one.
